# GoogleMap error 2

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I wrote this code in other to integrate google map v2 to my android app and i am getting errors. I need to know where i made a mistake. The code and the logcat error is listed below:

EkoMap.java:

```
package com.src.apps.myekoapp;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.wallet.Address;

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public class EkoMap extends Activity {
    private GoogleMap ekoMap;
    LocationManager locMan;
    Location lastLoc;
    LatLng lastLatLng;
    private Marker userMarker;
    private int user_icon;
    Geocoder mGeocoder;
    double lat, lng;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_fragment);
        user_icon = R.drawable.user_icon;

        // Setting zoom controls
        //ekoMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        try {
            if (ekoMap == null) {
                ekoMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                        R.id.the_map)).getMap();
            }
            if (ekoMap != null) {
                // ok - proceed
            }

            ekoMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Updating User Location
        updatePlaces();
        updateWithNewlocation(lastLoc);

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    // showing current location

    private void updatePlaces() {
        locMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        lastLoc = locMan.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        lat = lastLoc.getLatitude();
        lng = lastLoc.getLongitude();

        lastLatLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        if (userMarker != null)
            userMarker.remove();

        userMarker = ekoMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(lastLatLng)
                .title("You are here")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(user_icon))
                .snippet("Your last recorded location"));

        ekoMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(lastLatLng), 300,
                null);

    }

    // showing the new location as the user moves

    public void updateWithNewlocation(Location l) {
        mGeocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
        String addressString = "No address found";

        if (!Geocoder.isPresent())
            addressString = "No geocoder available";
        else {
            try {
                List<android.location.Address> address = mGeocoder
                        .getFromLocation(lat, lng, 1);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                if (address.size() > 0) {
                    android.location.Address addresses = address.get(0);

                    for (int i = 0; i < addresses.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                        sb.append(addresses.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                    sb.append(addresses.getLocality()).append("\n");
                    sb.append(addresses.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                    sb.append(addresses.getCountryName());
                }
                addressString = sb.toString();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("WHERE AM I", "IOException", e);
            }
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Your current Location is " + addressString, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Adding menus to change the look of the map
        MenuInflater mMenuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        mMenuInflater.inflate(R.menu.map_fragment_menu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem mMenuItem) {
        // Handle presses on the action bar items
        switch (mMenuItem.getItemId()) {

        // Handle up/home navigation
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;

            // Handle hybrid view
        case R.id.item_hybrid:
            try {
                ekoMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Handle satellite view
        case R.id.item_satellite:
            try {
                ekoMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Handle terrain view
        case R.id.item_terrain:
            try {
                ekoMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Handel about app
        case R.id.action_about:
            return true;

            // Handle call
        case R.id.action_call:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CallLASMA.class));

            // Return menuItem
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(mMenuItem);
        }
    }
}
```

LogCat error:

```
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.src.apps.myekoapp/com.src.apps.myekoapp.EkoMap}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1736)
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1752)
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:123)
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:993)
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:126)
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3997)
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:491)
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at com.src.apps.myekoapp.EkoMap.updatePlaces(EkoMap.java:81)
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at com.src.apps.myekoapp.EkoMap.onCreate(EkoMap.java:67)
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1048)
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1700)
06-26 17:28:18.096: E/AndroidRuntime(415):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

`locMan` is null.

Did you add the following permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: yes i did. you can check the previous question i asked called Googlemap error to see the manifest.xml file